# How to access HttpServletResponse in Spring Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a spring-boot app with swagger code generator. Since the controllers are autogenerated from swagger yaml I don't think I can modify the controllers to access the `HttpServletResponse`.

Is there a way to access the `HttpServletResponse` from a class annotated with `@Component`?

I am trying to access the `HttpServletResponse` instance in order to set a cookie.

Comment: HttpServletResponse is already injected, you can have it as a parameter in your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to touch the controller at all would be to make your bean a spring filter bean. This article here gives you details how to declare such bean. Once declare you need to bind it to url pointing to your controller method.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

It depends on What your final goal is.

Comment: Filter or interceptor are the way to go. give access to the request and response

Comment: @mavriksc exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides static class ([ServletRequestAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.6-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html)) that you can use to access request/response from any place in the application:

```
public void method() {
        ServletRequestAttributes ra = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (ra != null) {
            HttpServletRequest request = ra.getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = ra.getResponse();
        }
    }
```

> ra.getRequest() will return null if request has already been processed